# How to change prompt text in search widget of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, widget

I am developing a website through Wordpress.
I am using a searchbar widget but instead of the default prompt 'Search...' within the input field I want to customized prompt like 'Search by Product Code'

I am using the basic search code:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your code in the question :-)

Comment: yes sorry. edited the question

Comment: I think this answer can help you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102270/141641

Comment: Make a searchform.php page in your theme. If searchform.php doesn't exist wordpress will use their default one. I'd advise against using javascript... Just make the form how you want it.

Comment: Thanks @jrswgtr the post helped...and I could change the prompt

Comment: @AmritaDeb my pleasure ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the default WordPress search bar via a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Within your child theme, create a new file **searchform.php** you can copy this one: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/searchform.php

Within that you can then amend the **placeholder** value to match your requirements.

Thanks.